# Can't access some topics

Tags: bug, documentation

For about 5 days now I have not been able to access some topics.

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/640/control-flow
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/288/hashes
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/828/activerecord

For each of these topics I get the error message:

> `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`

**This happens for any topic I try to submit an edit to**.

Jut now I made this edit, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/3877/debugging#t=201607262323413987316 and now I cant access the topic, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/3877/debugging.

Comment: One sec ill update them...